# Bootstrap accordion different behavior for chrome and Mozila

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, mozilla

I have a bootstrap accordion in my app which is behaving differently.

I open a dropdown, select a radio option and I hit proceed button.

In chrome when I click `back` button on Chrome, The accordion is collapsed, but in Mozilla, when I hit `back`, the accordion remains open.

Why two different behaviors? Any solution to this case?

Comment: can you pls share your code .

Comment: I am not able to generate proper fiddle for the same. I'm trying to update the code

Answer (score 1):

Both browsers implement the behaviors differently as you have experienced.

Comment: But is there any know fix to this? That's what I am trying to find

Comment: Oh I see, are you using the default bootstrap accordion or one of the many add-on's people write for bootstrap?

Comment: I am using the default one

Comment: `<a class="collapser collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" ><span id=""></a>`

This